# backing up android device using adb

Tags: android, backup, adb

I am attempting to copy all the applications and data from a android tablet1 to another android tablet2. Both tablets has the same specification and is the same type.

My approach is to use the command

```
 adb backup -f my_backup.ab -apk -shared -all
```

to get all the files from tablet1 then use the command:

```
 adb restore my_backup.ab
```

to restore(basically copy) all the backed up files to tablet2.

The restore works fine, my problem is that sometimes backup does not backup all applications are all data on the device.

Do you have any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks for your response and time.

Comment: Belongs to Android.StackExchange

Answer (score 60):

Execute on your computer

```
adb backup -apk -shared -all
```

This should hopefully create backup.ab with all of your apps, OS, and data.
To restore, execute the following.

```
adb restore backup.ab
```

Comment: It looks like the restore command is wrong.
For Windows users there is no `sudo` command to use so I would rather revise the backup command too.

Comment: if you want to be sure that all data is baked up first run `adb root`

Comment: also, you might want to include -system.  It will bloat the backup, but it just depends on how deeply the the device needs to be "cloned".

Comment: -system is probably unnecessary because the default is -system already

Comment: I have just got a replacement phone and want to transfer everything over from my old one to my new one. My current device has an unlocked  bootloader, is running a custom Google Edition ROM, is 's-off'ed (HTC One M7) and rooted. How much of this will be transferred across?

Comment: what about whole  phone/tablet ROM?can do this with adb?

Answer (score 4):

If you do not have root access on tablet1, certain data will not be accessible by adb, such as private application data, hence they will not be backed up. Try running 'adb root' first.

Comment: not true, it is a true full backup as verified here:   
http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/guide-phone-backup-unlock-root-t1420351?nocache=1
http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-completely-backup-your-android-device-on-pc-without-root-access/
http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-nexus/general/guide-phone-backup-unlock-root-t1420351

Comment: I think, you mean the correct thing. Check out this brilliant answer by Izzy https://android.stackexchange.com/a/182384/340401