# Android: Transfer files/apps from android device to pc

Tags: android, file, sockets, transfer

I am developing an android application that enables user to transfer files from an android device to PC.

How can i transfer selected files/apps to a connected PC?

Comment: How are they "connected"? The phone can not control what the PC does, it has no control over e.g. the harddisk of the PC. You need to have software running on the PC that can communicate with your app. And apps can probably not be transferred at all since they are meant to be inaccessible so paid apps can not be shared freely.

Comment: They are connected via USB, My main concept on my application is to back up selected files/apps in my device.

Comment: USB does not support sockets or direct 2 way communication between an app and the PC. Maybe you just need to write a PC app that make http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225467/backing-up-android-device-using-adb simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a socket connection. your pc  would be your server and the android app would be your client. This way you can send data from your mobile device to your pc.

for example you can refer below link

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077322/core-java/sockets-programming-in-java-a-tutorial.html

this is basically written in java but similarly you can write it in android.